# Can I use the extra thermostat cable as C cable for wifi?

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I just purchased an ecobee4 and I found that I need C wire for wifi which is not connected to my current thermostat. However, there 2 extra wires I found in the wall. Could you use one of them for the C wire? Also the board has something already going in to C screw but I think its for something else? It's coming out of the separate brown cable. There is also one wire coming from brown cable going to yellow. I leave these 2 alone?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't need C for WiFi.   You need C for additional power to the thermostat.   You need the additional power for... among other things, WiFi.

Comment: Where does the brown cable go?  It is powering a doorbell?  Or what?

Comment: @Bryce -- my answer covers that.  (it's the cable to the air conditioner compressor)\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Go ahead, hook that blue wire up to C and use it for your Ecobee

As the terminal strip on your furnace control board is typical in that it has room for 2 wires on each screw, you can simply land the blue wire on the furnace control board's C terminal alongside the white wire that's already there.

BTW: the brown cable you're asking about can simply be left alone -- it's the cable that connects your thermostat's yellow wire (Y terminal) and the furnace control board's C terminal to the compressor contactor in your air conditioner so the thermostat can turn it on and off when things get sweltering in the summertime.

Comment: Thank you, Quick question, the brown cable has 2 wires coming out of, one is Yellow which is also going Y and C which is going C. So I leave the extra yellow as is correct? and just use the blue coming out of the white cable as my C.

Comment: @Sam -- that is correct.  the white wire from the brown cable needs to be left as-is as well